# Как получить путь классу java?

Tags: java

Имею некий обучавшийся проект, где использую большое количество пакетов.

Один пакет — это одна особенность языка (например, GUI, IO, *Celection*, и тд.). В проекте используются внешние ресурсы на ввод и вывод (jpeg, mp3, txt и тд.).

Указываю путь к файлу подобным образом – `nameFile = “file.txt”`. 
Выходить что все файлы из разных пакетов выводят файл в корень проекта.

Я хочу, что все выходные файлы выводились в пакет, где лежит класс. Чтобы я мог использовать одно и то же имя, не перезаписывая файл.

Как мне получить относительный  путь к классу, чтобы подписать этот путь к ресурсу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения директории, в которой находится класс, можно использовать такой код:

```
 File currentClass = new File(URLDecoder.decode(ВашКласс.class
                .getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation()
                .getPath(), "UTF-8"));
 String classDirectory = currentClass.getParent();
```

---

Лично я использую такую конструкцию с такими классами и распространяю по всему проекту, если проект завязан на работе с файлами:

Интерфейс:

```
public interface ApplicationPathManager {
    String getApplicationDatabaseDirectory();
    String getApplicationDataDirectory();
    String getApplicationTempDirectory();
    String getApplicationDirectory();
}
```

Стандартная реализация:

```
public class DefaultPathManager implements ApplicationPathManager {
    private String mApplicationDatabaseDirectory;
    private String mApplicationDataDirectory;
    private String mApplicationTempDirectory;
    private String mApplicationDirectory;

    public DefaultPathManager(String applicationDirectory) {
        this.mApplicationDirectory = applicationDirectory;

        this.mApplicationDatabaseDirectory = applicationDirectory + File.separatorChar + "database";
        this.mApplicationDataDirectory = applicationDirectory + File.separatorChar + "data";
        this.mApplicationTempDirectory = applicationDirectory + File.separatorChar + "temp";
    }

    @Override
    public String getApplicationDatabaseDirectory() {
        return mApplicationDatabaseDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public String getApplicationDataDirectory() {
        return mApplicationDataDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public String getApplicationTempDirectory() {
        return mApplicationTempDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public String getApplicationDirectory() {
        return mApplicationDirectory;
    }
}
```

Применение:

```
        File currentClass = new File(URLDecoder.decode(OSLoaderApplication.class
                .getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation()
                .getPath(), "UTF-8"));
        String jarDirectory = currentClass.getParent();
        mApplicationPathManager = new DefaultPathManager(jarDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
System.out.println(YourClassName.class.getResource("file_name.png").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Оно конечно возвращает мне путь к классу но, вначале есть приписка “file:/”, от которой придется избавиться. И дублировать запись вроде этого YourClassName не очень хорошо, но можно смериться.